# What's the difference between lgb.train() and lightgbm() in r?

Tags: r, lightgbm

I'm trying to build a regression model with R using lightGBM,
and i'm getting a bit confused with some functions and when/how to use them.

First one is what i've written in the title, what's the difference between lgb.train() and lightgbm()?

The description in the documentation(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lightgbm/lightgbm.pdf) says that lgb.train is 'Logic to train with LightGBM' and lightgbm is 'Simple interface for training a LightGBM model', while both their outcome value is lgb.Booster, a trained model.
One difference I've found is that lgb.train() does not work with valids = , while lightgbm() does.

Second one is about a function lgb.cv(), regarding a cross validation in lightGBM. How do you apply the output of lgb.cv() to a model?
As I understood from the documentation i've linked above, it seems like the output of both lgb.cv and lgb.train is a model.
Is it correct to use it like the example below?

```
lgbcv <- lgb.cv(params,
            lgbtrain,
            nrounds = 1000,
            nfold = 5, 
            early_stopping_rounds = 100,
            learning_rate = 1.0)

lgbcv <- lightgbm(params,
               lgbtrain,
               nrounds = 1000,
               early_stopping_rounds = 100,
               learning_rate = 1.0)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's the difference between lgb.train() and lightgbm()?

These functions both train a LightGBM model, they're just slightly different interfaces. The biggest difference is in how training data are prepared. LightGBM training requires a special LightGBM-specific representation of the training data, called a `Dataset`. To use `lgb.train()`, you have to construct one of these beforehand with `lgb.Dataset()`. `lightgbm()`, on the other hand, can accept a data frame, `data.table`, or matrix and will create the `Dataset` object for you.

Choose whichever method you feel has a more friendly interface...both will produce a single trained LightGBM model (class `"lgb.Booster"`).

> that lgb.train() does not work with valids = , while lightgbm() does.

This is not correct. Both functions accept the keyword argument `valids`. Run `?lgb.train` and `?lightgbm` for documentation on those methods.

> How do you apply the output of lgb.cv() to a model?

I'm not sure what you mean, but you can find an example of how to use `lgb.cv()` in the docs that show up when you run `?lgb.cv`.

```r
library(lightgbm)
data(agaricus.train, package = "lightgbm")
train <- agaricus.train
dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(train$data, label = train$label)
params <- list(objective = "regression", metric = "l2")
model <- lgb.cv(
  params = params
  , data = dtrain
  , nrounds = 5L
  , nfold = 3L
  , min_data = 1L
  , learning_rate = 1.0
)
```

This returns an object of class `"lgb.CVBooster"`. That object has multiple `"lgb.Booster"` objects in it (the trained models that `lightgbm()` or `lgb.train()` produce).

You can extract any one of these from `model$boosters`. However, in practice I don't recommend using the models from `lgb.cv()` directly. The goal of cross-validation is to get an estimate of the generalization error for a model. So you can use `lgb.cv()` to figure out the expected error for a given dataset + set of parameters (by looking at `model$record_evals` and `model$best_score`).